# Смущает вопрос из книги Р. Лафоре "ООП в С++"

Tags: c++, параметры, аргументы

В книге Р. Лафоре в 5 главе столкнулся с интересным 18 вопросом:

Когда аргумент передается в функцию по ссылке,

**а) внутри функции создаётся переменная, хранящая значение этого
аргумента;**

**б) функция не имеет доступа к значению аргумента;**

**в) в вызывающей программе создаётся временная переменная для хранения
значения аргумента;**

**г) функция получает доступ к аргументу в вызывающей программе.**

Я выбрал ответ **а)**, потому что, как сказал автор:

> Как мы видели, функция не имеет доступа к переменным аргументам, а работает со сделанными ей копиями.

а также

> Важной особенностью передачи аргументов по ссылке является то, что функция имеет прямой доступ к значениям аргументов.

Но что ввело меня в полнейший ступор, так это то, что правильный ответ - **г)**. Здесь есть какая-то тонкость или я что-то упустил?

Comment: передается по ссылке, значит это будет точно та-же переменная, что и при вызове, ну пока многопоточности нет...

Comment: дык, вариант (г) практически в точности повторяет вторую цитату... а первая цитата (и ответ (а)) относится к аргументам, передаваемым **по значению**...

Comment: Понимаете... Совсем строго - аргументом является именно ссылка, так что создается копия, но ссылки. Если рассматривать "значение аргумента" как передаваемый адрес - ну, тогда можно говорить об а), но все, ради чего этот опрос затевался - показать, что при этом изменения в функции затрагивают то, что передано в функцию извне. Передача по ссылке, передача по адресу - это в каком-то смысле эвфемизмы, потому что в этом случае по большому счету передается *по значению* адрес. Но их принято считать как бы отдельными типами передачи параметров в функцию. Так проще и удобнее :)

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как мы видели, функция не имеет доступа к переменным аргументам, а работает со сделанными ей копиями.

Это при передаче аргументов по значению (не по указателю, не по ссылке).

> Важной особенностью передачи аргументов по ссылке является то, что функция имеет прямой доступ к значениям аргументов.

Это при передаче аргументов по ссылке или по указателю.

Именно из второй цитаты следует, что правильный ответ Г). Функция имеет прямой доступ к значениям аргументов, которые хранятся в теле вызывающей функции. То есть может их как читать, так и перезаписывать.

Вот пример:

```
int a(int b)
{
    b = 5; //Это никак не влияет на переменную b в функции main
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 1;
    a(b); //Аргумент передан по значению
    cout << b; //Будет выведено 1
    return 0;
}
```

Пример 2:

```
int a(int &b)
{
    b = 5; //Переменная b внутри функции main будет перезаписана
    return b;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 1;
    a(b); //Аргумент передан по ссылке
    cout << b; //будет выведено 5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да просто можно было сказать TS, что ссылка это указатель который не может быть __пустым__, т.е. иметь не верный адрес или что еще.

Answer (score 1):

Вы *не различили* цитаты. Здесь идет речь про две *разные* концепции (передача по значению и по ссылке).

Отсюда следует, что правильный ответ на вопрос это *Г) функция получает доступ к аргументу в вызывающей программе*.

Выводы - самый лучший вариант передачи аргумента в функцию - по ссылке(правда литералы не прокатят(прокатят если сделать константную ссылку)). Это особенно экономно, когда параметр - структура или класс. Но не когда фундаментальная(int, bool и тд.) переменная, так как она маленькая и не нужны здесь ссылки(под капотом указатели, а разыменование указателей занимает время!)